TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined while setting up Sitecore JSS with Next.js
I’m new to Sitecore and both frontend and backend technologies. I’m trying to set up a JSS project using the following command using next.js :
npx create-sitecore-jss --templates nextjs --appName my-nextjs-app --fetchWith GraphQL

During the setup, I selected:

Linting for better practice
Server-Side Rendering (SSR) based on my project requirements
No XM Cloud

However, I encountered the following error:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value')

I’ve checked my Node.js and npm versions and confirmed they are compatible. I also cleared the npm cache and re-ran the command, but the error persists.
I would appreciate any guidance on what might be going wrong or if I missed any steps in the setup process. Thank you!

Can you add more about the error where in which file you are facing the error? You can check it on browser only in error popup modal

please add details including things like the stack trace, where the error is happening etc...

It seems like which field you are trying to fetch is having null value. So in order to fix this issue, you have two options:
1. Add the field value through the CMS.
2. Implement a null check in the code.
<heading>{fields?.pageTitle?.value?.toString() || 'Page'}</heading>

Here I'm adding Layout.tsx code
const Layout = ({ layoutData, headLinks }: LayoutProps): JSX.Element => {
  const { route } = layoutData.sitecore;

  const fields = route?.fields as RouteFields;

  return (
    <>
      <Scripts />
      <Head>
       <title>{fields?.pageTitle?.value?.toString() || 'Page'}</title>
        <link rel="icon" href={`${publicUrl}/favicon.ico`} />
        {headLinks.map((headLink) => (
          <link rel={headLink.rel} key={headLink.href} href={headLink.href} />
        ))}
      </Head>

      {/* <Navigation /> */}
      {/* root placeholder for the app, which we add components to using route data */}
      <div className="container">{route && <Placeholder name="jss-header" rendering={route} />}</div>
      <div className="container">{route && <Placeholder name="jss-main" rendering={route} />}</div>
      <div className="container footer">{route && <Placeholder name="jss-footer" rendering={route} />}</div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Layout;

Or you can take reference this question as well
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74832268/typeerror-cannot-read-properties-of-undefined-reading-call-on-next-js
Hope this help!!

I tried, it is not working.
Now it is failing for layout data case

Can you please add null check like this In layout.tsx file it should work.     "{fields?.pageTitle?.value?.toString() || 'Page'}"

I have added  layout.tsx code in my answer
